# How to execute two dependent odata url's in same session from C# Code

Tags: c#, odata

I need to call two odata URL's of sap from C# Code. 
The first URL will set the Filters and the second URL (generic URL) will give the actual response.

First URL:

https://<>/sap/opu/odata/SALM/TM_SERVICE/setFilters?sap-language=EN&filter='2%2Ctime%3D%E2%80%8E4%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E1%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E2019%E2%80%8E%20%E2%80%8E10%E2%80%8E%3A%E2%80%8E31%E2%80%8E%3A%E2%80%8E24%E2%80%8E%20%E2%80%8EAMc%3ATest%20Suite%20for%20Focused%20Build%2Cw%3A%2CT%3D<>'

Second URL :

https://<>//sap/opu/odata/SALM/TM_SERVICE/TILECollection(ConfigID='1%20',PageID='2%20',TileID='8%20')?$format=json&sap-language=EN

Second URL is generic and constant URL but after first execution of first URL with different parameter values second URL will give different response.

In a browser I am able to execute these two URL's and see the response difference with different parameter values.

Need C# Code to simulate the browser behavior. In C# Code second URL response is constant and not being changed.

Tried using following : WebRequest,HttpWebRequest, HttpClient,WebClient along with passing cookie ( cookie received from First response is passed to Request while executing the second url )

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
                    {
                        Credentials = credential,
                        CookieContainer = cookieContainer
                    };

                    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
                    {
                        using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("<<first url>>").Result)
                        {
                            Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestPlanSetFilters"], s));
                            IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>();
                            foreach (Cookie cookie in responseCookies)
                            {
                                cookieContainer.Add(cookie);
                            }
                        }

                            using (HttpResponseMessage response1 = client.GetAsync("<<second url>>").Result)
                            {
                                using (HttpContent content1 = response1.Content)
                                {
                                    var json2 = content1.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                             }                            
                        }                        

                    }
```

Comment: Use Fiddler to compare what your browser is doing to what your code is doing, that will give you the answer.

Comment: It turned out to be url issue instead of code issue.Issue has been resolved now.